# .git folder for Submodules

Tags: git, github

In one version of git, we have (git version `1.7.4.4`):

```
ProjectRoot/.git/modules/SubmoduleX/config
```

However in another computer we have (git version `1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)`):

```
ProjectRoot/SubmoduleX/.git/config
```

Why the discrepancy? When was this change done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have got the versions the other way around?

The change was introduced in `1.7.8`:

> When populating a new submodule directory with "git submodule
>   init",    the $GIT_DIR metainformation directory for submodules is
>   created inside    $GIT_DIR/modules// directory of the
>   superproject and referenced    via the gitfile mechanism. This is to
>   make it possible to switch    between commits in the superproject that
>   has and does not have the    submodule in the tree without re-cloning.

https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt

Comment: That 's the advantage: possible to switch between commits in the superproject that has and does not have the submodule in the tree without re-cloning

Answer (score 0):

Can centralize all metadata in the .git folder in root repository folder.

This is called separate git dir.